# Sharing image localy

Tags: android, image, android-intent, jpeg

Ok, I am using android studio and have hit a bit of a wall. I have two "activities" MainActivity and Main2Activity.

When I open Main2Activity I have a button, I want to press that button and use its background image for button on MainActivity. The idea is on Activity2 I click the button then on Main activity each button I click should the use the same background.

The image is a JPEG and is part of "Drawrable"

I am fairley new to android programming so would really appreciate the help.

Dan

Comment: I think the best for you is to use **startActivityForResult()** and **onActivityResult()** methods. [Look at this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/intents/result.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly..
In MainActivity2,

define a boolean

```
boolean changeImageBg = false;
```

in button onClick in this activity,

```
btn.setOnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
changeImageBg =true;
        }
    }
```

pass this boolean to MainActivity.

```
Intent  intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putBoolean("change", changeImageBg);
startActviity(intent);
```

In your MainActivity,

get the boolean from MainActivity2.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
boolean changeImageBg = intent.getBooleanExtra("change");
```

then perform the changes based on this boolean flag.

in Your MainActivity

```
if(changeImageBg) {
//change image background here
}
```

Let me know about this.

Comment: public void GET(View v) {
        
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        boolean changeImageBg = intent.getBooleanExtra("change");
        if(changeImageBg) {
button.setBackground(R.drawable.arrow_up_left_2);
        }

Comment: in View cannot be applied to (int)

Comment: Also the word "change" on MainActivity is kicking up an error
getBooleanExtra (string, Boolean) in Intent cannot be applied to (string

Comment: Kindly please learn how to use activities, intents, and first most is learn some Java, debugging and improve yourself to find error messages.

Comment: I know a little programming for android. Primarily I use .net and make windows programs. The jump over has been significant and has left me to learn a lot. But as with every single person I can't know everything and will ask for help from time to time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tweaked the above code and got it working.

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Boolean changeImageBg = intent.getBooleanExtra("change",false);
    if(changeImageBg) {
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arrow_up_left_2);
```

The Boolean was asking for a default value which I set to false.
Seems to have done the trick.

Thanks for the advice